# What is the meaning of positive lagrange multiplier?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I'm handling a maximization problem with a constraint and there is a sentence "but, the lagrange multiplier is positive".
I can't understand why that sentence is needed. Is there any difference between positive and negative lagrange multiplier?

Comment: We might know better why it makes a difference if we know the context of the problem. Do you mind putting the problem into the question?

Comment: @Fantini The question is finding FOC of profit maximization problem under the budget constraint.

Comment: Yes, but can you type the problem into the body of your question?

Comment: You are trying to find extrema of a function f on a level set of a function g. Then positivity of LM simply means that both f and g either increase or decrease at an extremal point and along the line normal to the level set.